# Triple Integral Containing Max, Gamma Function Analogy

Tags: integration, improper-integrals, gamma-function

From [experimentation](https://www.authorea.com/users/5445/articles/319559-title) I am pretty certain that
$$
G_3(n) = \int_0^\infty\int_0^\infty \int_0^\infty e^{-x_1-x_2-x_3}\max(|x_1-x_2|,|x_2-x_3|,|x_3-x_1|)^n\; dx_1 \,dx_2 \,dx_3= \Gamma(n+1)(2-2^{-n})
$$
The lower-dimensional version seems to be
$$
G_2(n) = \int_0^\infty\int_0^\infty e^{-x_1-x_2}\max(|x_1-x_2|)^n\; dx_1 \,dx_2 = \int_0^\infty x^n e^{-x} \; dx= \Gamma(n+1)
$$
so it is not unreasonable. Is there a way of proving/showing:
$$
G_3(n) = \Gamma(n+1)(2-2^{-n})\text{?}
$$
I'm interested in generalisations to higher dimensions.

Edit:

Thanks to Jack's answer I have also found
$$
G_4(n) = \Gamma(1+n)(3-3 \cdot 2^{-n} + 3^{-n})
$$
assuming the max of all $\binom{4}{2}$ differences of variables. It appears that for general $k$ we will have
$$
G_k(n) = (k-1) \int_0^\infty x^{n} e^{-(k-1)x}(e^{x}-1)^{k-2} \; dx
$$

Comment: Induction maybe?

Comment: Not sure that this would help, but you can write $$\max(|x_1-x_2|,|x_2-x_3|,|x_3-x_1|)=\lim_{m\to\infty}\sqrt[m]{(x_1-x_2)^m+(x_2-x_3)^m+(x_3-x_1)^m}$$ where $m$ is an even positive integer.

Comment: Note the typographical contrast between these two expressions: $$ \begin{align} & e^{-x_1-x_2-x_3}\text{max}(|x_1-x_2|,|x_2-x_3|,|x_3-x_1|)^n \\ \\ & e^{-x_1-x_2-x_3}\max(|x_1-x_2|,|x_2-x_3|,|x_3-x_1|)^n \end{align} $$ With \max, the spaces to the left and right of "max" depend on the context; with \text{max}, they don't. Also, there's this: $$ \begin{align} & \max_{x\,\in\,S} f(x) \\ \\ & \text{max}_{x\,\in\,S} f(x) \end{align} $$ The first uses \max and the second uses \text{max}. (In an inline, rather than displayed, setting, the subscript will be to the right, however.) $\qquad$

Comment: In higher dimensions, would you have $\max\{ |x_2-x_1|, \ldots, |x_k-x_{k-1}|, |x_1-x_k|\},$ forming a cycle of length $k,$ or would have have all $\binom k2$ absolute differences? Have you done any "experimentation" with those two possibilities?

Comment: @MichaelHardy Thanks for the LaTeX tips, I had been thinking all of the $\binom{k}{2}$ differences, such that it is the maximum separation between any of the $k$ draws from the distribution. I investigated integrating over $4$ variables, but couldn't find a pattern. Jack's answer seems to be the way to go here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By symmetry
$$\begin{eqnarray*} G_3(n)&=&6\iiint_{0\leq x_1\leq x_2 \leq x_3} e^{-(x_1+x_2+x_3)}(x_3-x_1)^n\,dx_1\,dx_2\,dx_3\\&=&6\iint_{0\leq x_1\leq x_3}e^{-(x_1+x_3)}\left(e^{-x_1}-e^{-x_3}\right)(x_3-x_1)^n\,dx_1\,dx_3\\&\stackrel{x_3\mapsto x_1+t}{=}&6\iint_{(0,+\infty)^2}e^{-(3x_1+t)}\left(1-e^{-t}\right)t^n\,dx_1\,dt\\&=&2\int_{0}^{+\infty}\left(e^{-t}-e^{-2t}\right)t^n\,dt\\&=&2\left(n!-\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}n!\right)=n!\left(2-\frac{1}{2^n}\right).\qquad\square\end{eqnarray*} $$
The generalization to $G_k(n)$ is straightforward.

Comment: Thanks, I have found $G_4(n)$ to  be $\Gamma(1+n)(3-3 \cdot 2^{-n} + 3^{-n})$.

Comment: I wonder whether there's a probabilistic argument for this.